# A Scapegoat Tree That Just Won't Balance

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

So, I'm working on this project for Comp 272, Data Structures and Algorithms, and before anyone asks I have no one to help me. It's an online program through Athabasca University and for some unknown reason they didn't supply me with a tutor for this course, which is a first... So... Yeah. The question is as follows:
"(20 marks) Exercise 8.2. Illustrate what happens when the sequence 1, 5, 2, 4, 3 is added to an empty ScapegoatTree, and show where the credits described in the proof of Lemma 8.3 go, and how they are used during this sequence of additions."

This is my code, its complete and it compiles:

```
/*
Name: Westcott.
Assignment: 2, Question 3.
Date: 08-26-2022.

    "(20 marks) Exercise 8.2. Illustrate what happens when the sequence 1, 5, 2, 4, 3 is added to an empty 
    ScapegoatTree, and show where the credits described in the proof of Lemma 8.3 go, and how they are used 
    during this sequence of additions."

*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Node {                // Originally I did this with Node as a subclass of sgTree but I         found that this
public:                     // way was easier. This is actually my second attempt, from     scratch, at doing this
    int data;               // problem. First version developed so many bugs I couldn't keep up with them.
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* parent;
    Node() : data(0), parent(NULL), left(NULL), right(NULL) {};
    Node(int x) : data(x), parent(NULL), left(NULL), right(NULL) {};
    ~Node() {};                                 // Normally I would do a little more work on clean up but... Yea this problem didn't leave me much room.
    Node* binarySearch(Node* root, int x);      // The Node class only holds binarySearch in addition to its
                                            // constructors/destructor, and of course the   Node*'s left, right and parent.
};


class sgTree {              // The sgTree keeps track of the root, n (the number of nodes in the tree), and q which is
public:                     // as Pat put it a 'high water mark'.
    Node* root;
    int n;
    int q;
    sgTree() : root(new Node()), n(1), q(1) {}
    sgTree(int x) : root(new Node(x)), n(0), q(0) {}
    ~sgTree() {
        delete root;
    }
    bool add(int x);                            // The add function is compounded, within it are findDepth and rebuild.
    bool removeX(int x);                        // removeX works, but it didn't have a big part to play in this question,
    int findDepth(Node* addedNode);             // but I'll include it to maintain our sorted set interface.
    void printTree(Node* u, int space) {        // This was extra function I wrote to help me problem solve.
        cout << "BINARY TREE DISPLAY" << endl;  // this version only prints a title and then it calls printTreeSub on line 46.
        cout << "________________________________________________\n\n" << endl;
        printTreeSub(u, space);
        cout << "________________________________________________\n\n" << endl;
    }
    int printTreeSub(Node* u, int space);           // Function definition for this is on line 81.
    int storeInArray(Node* ptr, Node* arr[], int i);// this is our function for storing all the elements of a tree in an array.
    int size(Node* u);                              // this is size, defined on line 74.
    void rebuild(Node* u);                          // And rebuild and buildBalanced are the stars of the show, defined on lines 262 and 282 
    Node* buildBalanced(Node** a, int i, int ns);   // just above the main() funciton.
};


int log32(int q) {          // As you can see there's two versions of this function. 
    int c = 0;              // this is supposed to return the log of n to base 3/2.
    while (q != 0) {        // The version below I got from this website: 
        q = q / 2;          // https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scapegoat-tree-set-1-introduction-insertion/
        c++;                // It works fine but I prefer the one I wrote.
    }                       // this is a much simpler function. It just divides q until its zero
    return c;               // and increments c on each division. Its not exact but it is based on what Pat said 
}                           // in this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGNUoDPVRCc&t=4852s

/*
static int const log32(int n)
{
    double const log23 = 2.4663034623764317;
    return (int)ceil(log23 * log(n));
}
*/

int sgTree::size(Node* u) {                         
    if (u == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + size(u->left) + size(u->right);      // Recursion in size();
}


int sgTree::printTreeSub(Node* u, int space) {              // Here is my strange print function
    if (u == NULL) return space;                            // I say strange because I'm not even 100% sure
    space--;                                                // how I got it to work. The order itself I worked out, but I built it 
    space -= printTreeSub(u->left, space);                  // and, originally, got a half decent tree, but then I just kept playing
    if (u->right == NULL && u->left == NULL) {              // around with increments, decrements, and returned values
        cout << "\n\n\n" << u->data << "\n\n\n" << endl;    // of space until it just sort of came together. 
        return 1;                                           // Basically it prints the left most Node first and then prints every node
    }                                                       // beneath that using recursion. I realized that by setting the for loop
    for (int i = space; i >= 0; i--) {                      // on line 89 I could imitate different nodes having different heights in 
        cout << "     ";                                    // the tree. I figured that using n as an input I could take advantage of
    }                                                       // the recursion to get an accurate tree. That much I understand.
    cout << "    " << u->data << "'s children are: ";       // But it didn't work out quite how I wanted it to so I just kept playing
    if (u->left != NULL) {                                  // with space increments and decrements on different sides of the tree until
        cout << u->left->data;                              // I got something pretty good.
    }
    else {
        cout << "NULL";
    }
    if (u->right != NULL) {
        cout << " and " << u->right->data;
    }
    else {
        cout << " NULL";
    }
    cout << "\n\n" << endl;
    space--;
    space -= printTreeSub(u->right, space);
    return 1;
}

int sgTree::storeInArray(Node* ptr, Node* a[], int i) {     // This function took me a while to figure out.
    if (ptr == NULL) {                                      // The recursive insertions of values using i, when
        return i;                                           // i is defined by the very same recursion, makes this
    }                                                       // a bit of a challenge to get your head around. 
    i = storeInArray(ptr->left, a, i);                      // Basically its just taking advantage on an inOrder
    a[i] = ptr;                                             // transversal to get the values stored into the array
    i++;                                                    // in order from least to greatest.
    return storeInArray(ptr->right, a, i);
}

Node* Node::binarySearch(Node* root, int x) {       // I covered this in another question. 
    if (root->data == x) {
        return root;
    }
    else if (x < root->data) {
        if (root->left == NULL) {
            return root;
        }
        return binarySearch(root->left, x);
    }
    else if (x > root->data) {
        if (root->right == NULL) {
            return root;
        }
        return binarySearch(root->right, x);
    }
}

bool sgTree::add(int x) {                           // The add function itself isn't too     difficult.
    Node* addedNode = new Node(x);                  // We make a Node using our data, then we search for that Node
    Node* parent = root->binarySearch(root, x);     // in the tree. I amended binarySearch to return the parent 
    addedNode->parent = parent;                     // if it hits a NULL child, on lines 127 and 133.
    if (x < parent->data) {                         // That way the new Node can just go into the returned parents child
        parent->left = addedNode;                   // here is where we choose whether it enters the left or the right.
    }
    else if (x > parent->data) {
        parent->right = addedNode;
    }
    int h = findDepth(addedNode);                   // We run findDepth() on the addedNode. I realize that this probably should
                                                // have been a part of the binarySearch, it means we go down
    if (h > log32(q)) {                             // the tree twice instead of once. I did look at changing binarySearch into searchAndDepth
                                                // having binarySearch return an int for the height isn't a problem, but then that would 
                                                // mess up removeX and, I don't know. What's more important?
        Node* w = addedNode->parent;                // If this were going to be a database hosting millions of pieces of data I would give
        while (3 * size(w) < 2 * size(w->parent)) { // that alot more consideration but, this is just an exercise after all so...
            w = w->parent;                          // From there, we compare our height to the value output by log32(q) on line 152. 
        }   
        rebuild(w);                                 // This expression 3 * size(w) < 2 * size(w->parent) is the formula on page 178 rewritten
        //rebuild(root);                            // as a cross multiplication, clever. It keeps going up the tree until we find the scapegoat w.
        // This is a much nicer result. 
        //See line 311.
    }                                               // Now, this is where my problems began. Pat says that this line should read: rebuild(w->parent);       
    n++;                                            // but when I do that I get an error when w is the root. Because then w->parent is NULL. And in that case
    q++;                                            // line 258 throws an error because we're trying to set p equal to NULL's parent. It's not there.
    return true;                                    // So my work around was to just offset this by one and send rebuild(w). But that doesn't seem
}                                                   // to balance the tree just right. In fact, the best tree results when we replace w with root.
                                                    // and just rebalance the whole tree. But in any case, we increment n and q and lets pick this up on line 256.
int sgTree::findDepth(Node* addedNode) {
int d = 0;
    while (addedNode != root) {
        addedNode = addedNode->parent;
        d++;
    }
    return d;
}


bool sgTree::removeX(int x) {
    Node* u = root->binarySearch(root, x);
    if (u->left == NULL && u->right == NULL) {
        if (u == u->parent->left) {
            u->parent->left = NULL;
        }
        if (u == u->parent->right) {
            u->parent->right = NULL;
        }
        cout << u->data << " deleted" << endl;
        n--;
        delete u;
        return true;
    }
    if (u->left != NULL && u->right == NULL) {
        if (u->parent->left = u) {
            u->parent->left = u->left;
        }
        else if (u->parent->right = u) {
            u->parent->right = u->left;
        }
        cout << u->data << " deleted" << endl;
        n--;
        delete u;
        return true;
    }
    if (u->left == NULL && u->right != NULL) {
        if (u == u->parent->left) {
            u->parent->left = u->right;
            u->right->parent = u->parent;
        }
        else if (u == u->parent->right) {
            u->parent->right = u->right;
            u->right->parent = u->parent;
        }
        cout << u->data << " deleted" << endl;
        n--;
        delete u;
        return true;
    }
    if (u->left != NULL && u->right != NULL) {
        Node* X = u->right;
        if (X->left == NULL) {
            X->left = u->left;
            if (u->parent != NULL) {
                if (u->parent->right == u) {
                    u->parent->right == X;
                }
                else if (u->parent->left == u) {
                    u->parent->left = X;
                }
            }
            else {
                root = X;
            }
            X->parent = u->parent;
            cout << u->data << " deleted" << endl;
            n--;
            delete u;
            return true;
        }
        while (X->left != NULL) {
            X = X->left;
        }
        X->parent->left = NULL;
        X->left = u->left;
        X->right = u->right;
        if (u->parent != NULL) {
            X->parent = u->parent;
        }
        cout << u->data << " deleted" << endl;
        n--;
        root = X;
        delete u;
        return true;
    }
}



void sgTree::rebuild(Node* u) {
    int ns = size(u);                       // Everything is pretty kosher here. Just get the number of nodes in the subtree.
    Node* p = u->parent;                    // Originally I had n here instead of ns and... I don't want to talk about how long it took me to find that mistake...
    /* It's funny because while writing the comments for this I'm like "Oh, hang on, if I just push the definition of p behind the if statement on line 262
and evaluate for whether or not u is NULL instead of p, that should solve all my problems! Yea, no, it doesn't. Because then for some reason it tries rebalancing 
empty tree and... Yea I just have to stop myself from trying to fix this because everytime I do I get caught in an infinite loop of me chasing my tail in errors. 
I think a solution could be found in buildBalanced, and I literally went through that function line by line, trying to comprehend a work around. I've included at 
a photograph of that white board. Yea this is the code that Pat gave us... and its garbage. It doesn't work. Maybe its a C++ thing, I don't know... But I'm 
getting frustrated again so I'm going to stop thinking about this part RIGHT HERE, and move on LOL*/
    Node** a = new Node * [ns];             // a Node pointer-pointer array... again, another     fine piece of code from the textbook. Sorry, trying to stay positive here.
    storeInArray(u, a, 0);                  // See Line 112
    if (p == NULL) {                        // Okay, once we have our array we use buildBalanced to rebuild the subtree with respect to which
        root = buildBalanced(a, 0, ns);     // child u is relative to its parent.
        root->parent = NULL;                // See line 281 for buildBalanced().
    }
    else if (p->right == u) {
        p->right = buildBalanced(a, 0, ns);
        p->right->parent = p;
    }
    else {
        p->left = buildBalanced(a, 0, ns);
        p->left->parent = p;
    }
}

Node* sgTree::buildBalanced(Node** a, int i, int ns) {          // This is without a doubt one of the hardest functions I've ever had
    if (ns == 0) {                                              // the displeasure of trying to understand... Trying to stay positive.
        return NULL;                                            // I've gone through it, in a line by line implementation of the array:
    }                                                           // a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} you can find that analysis in 
    int m = ns / 2;                                             // the photo buildBalanced_Analysis.
    a[i + m]->left = buildBalanced(a, i, m);                    // As confusing as it is, I have to admit that it is a beautiful function.
    if (a[i + m]->left != NULL) {                               // It basically uses the two integers i and m to simultaneously 
        a[i + m]->left->parent = a[i + m];                      // regulate the organization of the new tree and to specifically  
    }                                                           // grab the right value from the array when its needed. 
    a[i + m]->right = buildBalanced(a, i + m + 1, ns - m - 1);  // but trying to map this out didn't help me to solve the issues I've been having. 
    if (a[i + m]->right != NULL) {
        a[i + m]->right->parent = a[i + m];
    }
    return a[i + m];
}


int main() {
    sgTree newTree(1);  

    int a[] = { 5, 2, 4, 3 };

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])); i++) {
        newTree.add(a[i]);
    }
    newTree.printTree(newTree.root, newTree.n);

        /*
    This is a nice test, when paired with rebuild(root), that too me is the only thing that         approaches redeeming this whole question.
    sgTree newTreeB(1);

    int b[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0])); i++) {
        newTreeB.add(b[i]);
    }
    newTreeB.printTree(newTreeB.root, newTreeB.n);
    */
}
```

Now the issue itself is not that hard to understand. My tree should look like this:

[image: TreeShouldLookLike]
But instead, it looks like this, with 5 at the root and the values 1 and 4 as the leaves:

[image]

I'm confident that the problem lives somewhere around line 159 and in those first few calls to buildBalanced. The comments in the code itself elaborate more on the issue. I've spent days just pouring over this trying everything I can think of to make it work and... Yeah... I just can't figure it out.

Comment: That's quite a lot of debugging you're asking us to do. My advice is to refactor your code such that you don't mutate an existing tree, but instead return a new one with the the needed addition / removal / anything else. That will significantly reduce your chances of making a mistake. And after you get that working, you will have something working to compare against if you absolutely must have a version that mutates the tree.

Comment: Some advice from having debugged a [large and annoying tree library in C++](https://www.davideisenstat.com/dtree/):

1.  Parent pointers create a bunch of annoying special cases. Scapegoat trees don't need them; you can just keep a separate stack.

2.  My favorite tree display function prints out trees rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. It takes a tree node and an indentation length as input, prints the right child recursively at indent + 2, prints the data at indent, prints the left child at indent + 2.

Comment: 3.  log32 is computing a log base 2, not 3/2, which allows more freedom to leave unbalanced trees. Rebuilding w instead of its parent also has this effect. Rebuilding from the root every time is wasteful. In general, there are many ways that scapegoat trees could work, but you have to follow the instructions exactly to get the exact result.

4.  I have a PhD in algorithms and TBH with the exception of B-trees and variants, I think learning how balanced trees work is a waste of time for most people.

Comment: @David Eisenstat, your advice seems pretty helpful but I'm not sure what you mean by a "you can just keep a separate stack." LOL I do appreciate you saying this: "I have a PhD in algorithms and TBH with the exception of B-trees and variants, I think learning how balanced trees work is a waste of time for most people."

I'm not so sure I'd ever want to do this in a job. It is infuriating. As you said everything has to be perfect or it just unravels in a thousand different directions.

Comment: Oh nvm, I know what you mean. Like don't bother with the parent pointer in Node itself. Just keep a separate like array or something that'll record the relationships? I think the textbook mentioned that.